Can the manifold boundary equation $\partial W=M$ possess more than 1 contractible solution?
Are there two non homeomorphic compact smooth  contractible manifolds $W_1,W_2$ such that their boundaries are diffeomorphic manifolds? Is there an example of this situation such that the boundary is a parallelizable manifold or even a Lie group?
This  question was asked  here  without "contractible" assumption

Not if $dim(W_i)= 4$, here.

According to Corollary 2.1 of this paper by Price, this is also not possible if $dim W_i \geq 5$. The method of proof is beyond my knowledge, so I'll let someone else comment on this.
